# How to get current page URL for multisite wordpress deployment

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to find the URL of the current page on wordpress.  I have been using this so far -

```
$cur_page_url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

But this doesn't work in a multisite deployment where the website address is like `site1.example.com`.  In such a case, `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` returns `example.com` instead of `site1.example.com`.

What should I use to get correct page URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `HTTP_HOST` instead of `SERVER_NAME`

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```